# Clarification on ATTiny45

Tags: attiny

What is the functionality of negative reset pin in ATTiny45? Am I correct that reset pin is used to reset the controller to some random state or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RESET does not reset the device to a "random" state at all.  The reset behavior is well defined and documented:

According to the Microchip ATTiny45 datasheet at:

[ATTiny45](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf)

[image: ATTiny 45 Reset Pin]

What happens is documented here:

[image: Reset Behavior]